# How to remove pattern matching for verifying user information in scala?

Tags: scala, switch-statement, pattern-matching

I am new to Scala as have been java developer until now.

I have a functionality to login like where user can have multiple passwords:

```
def login(User user) : Boolean = {
 String username = user.username
 String password = user.password

 (username, password) match {
   case("Amit","AmitSecret1" | "AmitSecret2") => true
   case("Rahul","Atemporary") => true
   case("Tom","Howareyou") => true
   case("Roger","Dummy") => true
   ...
   ... // lot of other cases
   case("_","_") => false
 }

}
```

Is there any other way of verifying login check without pattern matching which does not involves **case** for every combination?

Comment: Note that in Scala we write `user: User` not `User user`, and `val username: String` not `String username`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a `Map[Username, Set[Password]]` you could then do:

```scala
def login(user: User): UserStatus = {
  map.get(key = user.username).fold(ifEmpty = UserDoesNotExist) { passwords =>
    if (passwords.contains(user.password))
      AuthenticatedUser
    else
      BadPassword
  }
```

I just made up the whole `UserStatus` ADT, but I hope the intent is clear.